# Removing the prefix of a string in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have two columns. One containing a prefix (nvarchar), and the next containing an nvarchar I wish to remove said prefix from, we'll name said column 'words'. Normally going `right(words, len(words) - len(prefix)` would get me that answer. However let's say there is two spaces at the beginning of words and the prefix is a single space. So I'm trying to remove just one space from the beginning of the word. len(prefix) will return 0. datalength(prefix) will return 1 however due to some characters taking 2 bytes, I don't believe datalength to be the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
RIGHT(words, LEN(words) - (LEN(prefix+'?')-1))
```

**EDITED :**

May be you will find this one "cleaner" :

```
RIGHT(words, LEN(words) - DATALENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),prefix)))
```

Answer (score 2):

CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(prefix,words) = 1 THEN RIGHT(words, LEN(words) - LEN(prefix)) ELSE words END

this makes sure prefix starts at the beginning, not at the middle or anywhere in the words.

Comment: For other googlers, MySQL version: `CASE WHEN POSITION(prefix IN words) = 1 THEN RIGHT(words, CHAR_LENGTH(words) - CHAR_LENGTH(prefix)) ELSE words END`